# C# Forms. How do I refer to a control from within that control

Tags: c#, forms, controls

I wrote a piece of code which convert the written language to Hebrew (via a reference I developed). 
When for example, when I enter a textbox control and I need it to get writing in Hebrew I add to its Enter event the following:

```
private void txtTestDirectionRTL_Enter(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        HebChng ();
        txtTestDirectionRTL.RightToLeft = RightToLeft.Yes;
    }
```

The HebChng convert the input language to Hebrew.
Now, the second line of code determines the flow direction for that textbox. 
What I would like to do is to refer to that control by other meanings than its explicit name.

The keyword "this" refers to the class. Is there anything that I can use to refer to the name of the control I'm in?

Can this be done?

Comment: `(TextBox)sender` usually works for events from the WinForms UI components (obviously change TextBox to the component type).

Answer (score 1):

The method has a parameter "object sender" - you can use that by casting it to the correct class. For example:

```
private void txtTestDirectionRTL_Enter(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
  HebChng ();
  TextBox myControl = (TextBox)sender;
  myControl.RightToLeft = RightToLeft.Yes;
}
```

Note that this is applicable to all control event handlers - the first parameter is an object which is a reference to the originating control (i.e. the "sender"). This should allow you to use the same event handler for multiple controls if you override the handlers automatically generated by Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

you can get the object via the sender your event function like so

```
(sender as TextBox).RightToLeft   = RightToLeft.Yes;
```